# SignIn not defined google action

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to request a user's sign in details using this guide:

[account linking guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in)]

I am using the node js actions on google library and have copied the guide so I have the following fufillment code:

```
const app = dialogflow({debug: true, clientId:'*.apps.googleusercontent.com'});
var firebase = require('firebase');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv) =>{
conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});

app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`)
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`)
  }
});
```

when I play the action in the simulator it says 'final response must be set'. I checked my logs in my firebase function and got the following error:

```
ReferenceError: SignIn is not defined
    at app.intent (/srv/index.js:167:15)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:149:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
    at Function.handler (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:84:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:55:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:22:71
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `SignIn` object from the actions-on-google library, in the same way as you have imported the `dialogflow` method. You can do this with

```
const {
  dialogflow,
  SignIn
} = require('actions-on-google');
```

Located before you use those objects.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! However I have realised that this SignIn method only works on devices with the actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT surface capability. This is a problem since I want to be able to perform this function using the google home, which doesn't have a screen. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If this answer helps, upvoting and/or accepting it are always appreciated. It sounds like you're asking a different question, and that is best handled with a new StackOverflow question.